# i want to add two new colomns to database how can i?

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, android-sql

i have five tables in my database i want to add two more colomns to only one table
how can i please help me thanks in advance.
this is my tables

```
                   sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_ProductSales_TABLE);
                 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_UNIT_TABLE);
                  sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_STOCK_TABLE);
                 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_OrderSales_TABLE);(i want to add two coloms to this table)
                sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_Prod_TABLE);
                 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_CAT_TABLE);
```

how to excute onupgrade method
what should i write for updating table and non updating table in android

Comment: What is `CREATE_OrderSales_TABLE`? I [presume](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) it is a string, but what is its value? How do you set its value?

Answer (score 0):

After the table is created you can use an alter statement to add columns such as

```
ALTER TABLE {OrderSales_Table} ADD COLUMN ColumnName {Integer};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` class which I use to create my tables.

take a look at my class

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Information
public static final String DB_NAME = "ROADTRIP_DB";

// database version
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

//<editor-fold desc = "TABLE NAMES">
public static final String DETAILS = "details";
//</editor-fold>

//<editor-fold desc="TABLE DETAILS">
public static final String ID = "_id";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String EMAIL = "email";
public static final String MOBILE = "mobile";
public static final String DATETIMESTAMP = "datetimestamp";
public static final String STATUS = "status";
//</editor-fold>


//<editor-fold desc="CREATE_ROADTRIP_TABLE">
private static final String CREATE_ROADTRIP_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DETAILS + "("
        + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + NAME + " VARCHAR,"
        + EMAIL + " VARCHAR,"
        + MOBILE + " VARCHAR,"
        + DATETIMESTAMP + " DATETIME,"
        + STATUS + " INTEGER)";
//</editor-fold>


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ROADTRIP_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I also use a another class to add a command on my database

```
public class DBManager {

private DBHelper DBHelper;

private Context context;

private SQLiteDatabase database;

public DBManager(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
    DBHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    database = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

//inserting data to database
//<editor-fold desc = "insertToDetails">
public void insertToDetails(String name,
                                  String email,
                                  String mobile,
                                  String datetimestamp,
                                  String status) {

    ContentValues contentValue = new ContentValues();
    contentValue.put(DBHelper.NAME, name);
    contentValue.put(DBHelper.EMAIL, email);
    contentValue.put(DBHelper.MOBILE, mobile);
    contentValue.put(DBHelper.DATETIMESTAMP, datetimestamp);
    contentValue.put(DBHelper.STATUS, status);

    database.insert(DETAILS, null, contentValue);
}
//</editor-fold>

//for getting the data from database fuction
public Cursor fetchData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            DBHelper.ID,
            DBHelper.NAME,
            DBHelper.EMAIL,
            DBHelper.MOBILE
    };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DETAILS, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

}

And when i want to add a data to my `database`. i just call

```
   dbManager.insertToDetails("column1","column2"...);
```

take a time to read this. it really make your life with `database` easier

**EDIT**

before you can use this, make sure you have to declare this:

```
SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
DBHelper dbHelper;
DBManager dbManager;
```

and call this on your `onCreate` (`for extends AppCompactActivity`) or `onCreateView` (for `Fragment`) whenever you want to use your database to prevent Database Leaks. Hope this helps

```
dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext());
sqldb = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
dbManager = new DBManager(getActivity());
dbManager.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter statement to add new column like as

sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Tablename ADD COLUMN Newcolumn VARCHAR DEFAULT 0");